# How do I pull out multiple values in one column to create new rows with those values instead (repeating all other information from original row)?

Tags: excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet with 12+ columns and 200+ rows.  In one of the columns (ColB), there are multiple values associated with a single row.  I would like to convert such records to multiple rows with single value in Column B.  In other words, I'd like to convert this:

---

[ColA]    [ColB]    [ColC]

[blue]  [1, 4, 7] [open]
[red]    [2, 3]     [closed]
[green]  [5]   [open]

---

to this:

---

[ColA]    [ColB]    [ColC]

[blue]  [1] [open]
[blue]  [4] [open]
[blue]  [7] [open]
[red]    [2]     [closed]
[red]    [3]     [closed]
[green]  [5]   [open]

---

Any suggestions?   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My favorite way to process data in Excel is with a Range object representing one row of data (which I call a "cursor"). You can use the Offset method to move the cursor down one row, and loop until a specific cell in the cursor is empty. There are many ways to identify the "last row" in an Excel worksheet, but they all have drawbacks - I just prefer to identify a column that should never be empty in my data and terminate the loop when you reach a blank cell.

```
Dim cursor As Range
Dim x As Variant
Dim i As Long

Set cursor = Range("A2:C2")

Do Until IsEmpty(cursor(1))
    x = Split(cursor(2), ",")

    If UBound(x) > 0 Then
        cursor(2) = x(0)
        For i = 1 To UBound(x)
            cursor.EntireRow.Insert
            With cursor.Offset(-1)
                cursor.Copy .Cells(1)
                .Cells(2) = x(i)
            End With
        Next
    End If

    Set cursor = cursor.Offset(1)
Loop
```

Comment: I'm afraid I'm such a novice that this doesn't make a lot of sense to me!  Where would I enter this code?  If I have 12 columns of data, am I offsetting the data from the other 11 columns? (Not familiar with OFFSET or range object..."  Thank you!

Comment: No problem. This code would go in a Sub in the VBA project for the Workbook. I found a good tutorial for getting started in VBA here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814737(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: To adapt it for more columns, you would need to change the line with Range("A2:C2") to refer to all columns, and change the references to cursor(2) and .Cells(2) to refer to the index of the cell that contains the multiple values.